# Wordpress CMS cannot upload import file(XML)

Tags: php, wordpress

My friend has a website http://bakubusinessconsulting.com where we can see 3 languages Russian and English version's theme/design was different (like russian). I tried to edit it and make it like AZ theme. I uploaded all plugin files and tried to do something but I couldn't. Then I tried to export file and got XML and now I want to import it but I get the following error:

> This webpage is temproraily  moved exc .
>   . http://bakubusinessconsulting.com/en/wp-admin/admin.php?import=wordpress&step=1&_wpnonce=8ecc88faf7e

I need your help very much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to put a little more effort in grammar and post formatting, it is really hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: My english is little bit bad. I have xml file(import file) via wp importer I tried to import it to my wordpress cms.I get an error can not install please I need this help as soon as possible